# using php to login, when the user click the submit button it still directs the user to my connectivity.php

Tags: php, html, authentication

As the title states when the user clicks the submit button it will take the suer to a blank connectivity.php page. The problem is however it works perfectly if the user enters their username and password. If they leave it blank thats when i goes to the blank connectivity page. Im having problems throwing up an error message.

nav.php(nav bar)

```
<div id="Sign-In">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right"  method="POST" action="Login/connectivity.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="user" side="40">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  name="pass" side="40">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Log-In">Log In</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
```

nav.php cont

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    if(!$_POST["user"]) {

            $error.="<br />Please enter your username";

        }
    if(!$_POST["pass"]) {

            $error.="<br />Please enter your Password";

        } 
    if($error){

        $result ='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong> '.$error.'</div>';

        } 
}
?>
```

I would like the div to pop up if its missing information. before it heads to `connectivity.php`

To better ask the question. I would like when the user presses to log-in button, the script at the top runs, IF the form is missing data the  wont run UNTIL they add the missing information, THEN the  will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if(!isset($_POST['user']) and empty( $_POST['user']))
```

To check if form not empty.
You need client side validation to prevent redirecting to server add the word   `required`  at the end of input tag

Comment: that sadly hasn't changed anything. it still takes me to connectivity.php

Comment: Please Post your error messages editing your question

Comment: Thats the problem there is no error message. In stead of alerting the missing form information is just continues to go to connectivity.php(which is a script) and stops there. If the username and pass is correct it redirects to index.html.

Comment: maybe i need to rephrase my question. If the form is missing any data, i want to page to STOP the <form action="">, perform some script till the user fixes the problem. THEN run the <form action="">

Comment: did you tried changing the submit and pass to this format.

Comment: Yes i have and it still heads to connectivity.php